# Need some insights and advice to sort a date from file

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting

I have a project, one of my tasks is to sorting a file by name.

Some basic info:
I have a project which contain a calss of House's , and each house contains some people's.

I have everything works fine, after I made all the objects I have arraylist which I save to file by ObejectOutputStream, and same to read from the file.

my last part is to sort this file by family name, without saving data on a temp array and manipulate the temp, and just when I finish, than save the new sorted array on the file again.

again, I cannot extract the file data, I need to manipulate the data on the file.
the file hierarchy:
ArrayList of House's --(contain)--> array of people (family)
I need to sort by family name, that means to sort the House's.

I don't need you to write the code for me, just advice what is the best way to this?
thanks who ever can help me :).

Comment: How is your file? Post a piece of it please.

Answer (score 0):

Here, there is an example of sorting objects in an ArrayList.

You can use, **Comparable** or **Comparator**.

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-of-object-sort-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Hmm, I did it.  In order to manipulate data you need to load it to memory first. You can manipulate the bits directly but I would not recommend that, I think the best way is to load the data to a structure in memory and do the sort. That's is why I recommend the answer before